# What are the percentage signs for in the sudoers file?

Tags: linux, sudoers

In my sudoers file, there are lines that begin with `#`, lines that begin with `%` and lines that begin with neither. The `#` is definitely being used to comment out lines, but what does the `%` do? Is it a comment marker too?

Comment: In addition to the given answer: Linux manpages do not only exist for commands (e.g. "man visudo") but also for many configuration files (e.g. "man fstab"). In this case "man sudoers" teaches you more than you ever wanted to know about setting up sudo.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A percent sign is used to indicate that the identifier that follows should be used as the name of a group instead of a user.